# Mandar uma string em javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Há alguma maneira de mandar uma string por parâmetros em `javascript`?

Eu tenho algo do tipo:

```
<i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="en('.$datas['contribuinte'].')"></i>
```

Este botão quando clicar, tem de levar a variável para a função, mas às vezes a variável dentro pode conter zeros à esquerda, sendo assim a função reconhece como inteiro e tira os zeros, por isso quero transformá-la em string.

Função:

```
    function en(x)
{
    window.open("en/vers.php?cls="+x,"_blank");
}
```

Exemplo:
Se a variável conter "000000001" eu não queria que a função transformasse em "1".

Comment: Nesse caso tens de tratar no PHP, ou seja fazer uma string no lado do PHP. É o mais correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor coisa que podes fazer e cria a lógica em PHP. Também podes fazer em javascript.

Poder fazer algo assim.

```
if(is_numeric($datas['contribuinte'])) {
    $myvar = (int)$datas['contribuinte'];
} else {
    $myvar = $datas['contribuinte'];
}
```

E agora no front-end

```
onclick="en('.$myvar.');"
```